# Magento 1.9.2.1 Cron Permission denied

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

I heve crontab `* * * * * /bin/sh /home/mydomaindirectory/mydomain.com/www/cron.sh` but cron doesn't work. Has error:

> /home/mydomaindirectory/mydomain.com/www/cron.sh: line 47:
>   /home/mydomaindirectory/mydomain.com/www/cron.php: Permission denied

How can I fix it?

Comment: who owns the file? is file readable?

Comment: Owns my ssh user, file is readable

Comment: Sounds like you're running on a server where the http server runs as a different user from the login account. Look in var/cache and see who owns the cache folders. If it's something like `www-data` you will need to address group ownership rights to be given permission to run run `cron.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the php binary file is not on the linux path. If you've compiled it yourself, try:-

```
sudo ln -s <path to your php bin folder>/php /usr/bin/php
```